# Why is in the following similar codes one giving runtime error and other is not

Tags: c++, runtime

Well this is really weird
Consider the following two codes :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int* ptr[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *ptr[i]=a[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(ptr[i]);
    }
}
```

AND

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int* ptr[5];


        *ptr[0]=a[0];
        *ptr[1]=a[1];
        *ptr[2]=a[2];
        *ptr[3]=a[3];
        *ptr[4]=a[4];




       cout<<*(ptr[0])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[1])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[2])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[3])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[4])<<endl;


}
```

The first one gives runtime errorr , while the seconde one gives 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 output , I can't find the difference between the two codes , can anyone help me to find the difference .

Comment: `int* ptr[5];` doesn't seem right to me... Shouldn't it be `int ptr[5];`? Well if you really like to stick with pointers then you SHOULD do `*(ptr[i])` etc. etc...

Comment: @Ruks well it's correct, I suppose as its an array of pointers

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @rsjaffe Just runtime error

Comment: @AyushMangal Look at the for loop of the first code... It should be `*(ptr[i])`

Comment: @Ruks I can't get it

Comment: why does the second code works

Comment: @Ruks even after *(ptr[i]) it gives runtime error

Comment: Simple answer, You have not allocated the pointer... So `ptr[i] = &a[i]` is the correct answer...

Comment: @Ruks yeah I was also thinking that at first but then why is the second code working

Comment: I don't think the second code works... Try it in some other compiler, like [WandBox](https://wandbox.org/)...

Comment: Ok , yup got error ,  I suppose its a problem of the ideone compiler, but wait I tried the second code in codeblocks , if u try to assign only the first two elements it works , but if you try to assign more than 2 then it gives runtime error

Comment: @AyushMangal I think that is a bug, that shouldn't happen... It will break even if you try to assign **one** element to it... Which compiler are you using in Code::Blocks?

Comment: @Ruks I am using  GNU GCC

Comment: Or with less sarcasm, nothing says bad code that invokes Undefined behaviour will cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have both runtime errors.
The result of recoding with the pointer variable below.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int* ptr[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ptr[i]=&a[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(ptr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the question, it looks like the OP wants an **array of pointers**...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int* ptr[5];


        *ptr[0]=a[0];
        *ptr[1]=a[1];





       cout<<*(ptr[0])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[1])<<endl;




}
```

the above code runs fine and gives output 1, 2
 but

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int* ptr[5];


        *ptr[0]=a[0];
        *ptr[1]=a[1];
        *ptr[2]=a[2];




       cout<<*(ptr[0])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[1])<<endl;
       cout<<*(ptr[2])<<endl;




}
```

this code gives runtime error on codeblocks(gcc) , I am just getting more confused

Comment: I think your compiler is broken... what you are trying to do is illegal! You should ***NEVER*** dereference a pointer without allocating it!!

Comment: yes I also know , but using such a standard GNU GCC compiler shouldn't have a bug , and even IDEONE websites compiler is having a problem then

Comment: Which version of GNU GCC is it? Looks like they allocate the pointer automatically somehow?... Look at [this](https://ideone.com/GT9MQr) if you think I am wrong...

Comment: Tried your first code in [WandBox](https://wandbox.org/) and set GCC version to 5.1.0 and it gives **segmentation fault**...

Comment: ok , I suppose its a problem with codeblocks or ideone itself

Comment: Looks like they encourage undefined behavior... which in itself, is bad practice...  A pointer should always be allocated before use in dereferencing... So, in conclusion, you can say that this code is not portable and only works on these compilers (with a few exceptions)... You should consider installing a newer version of GCC in Code::Blocks or, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which should have been the answer from the very beginning...

Comment: Well I am actually quite new to coding and am in my first year in the university, and this was asked my one of my friends and yeah I also use vectors mostly

Comment: @Ruks: you could read more on undefined behavior in C++ (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). This has nothing to do with compilers and everything with how C++ tries to be as fast as possible. It expects programmers to know what they're doing and to not have code with UB. The worst behavior of UB is that it seems to work as expected, because it could stop working as expected at any time, so now you have some kind of time bomb.

Answer (score 0):

It is already established that

```
*ptr[0] = a[0];
```

with unallocated pointer is undefined behavior.

The solution

```
ptr[0] = &a[0];
```

is also already given. This works, but it is limited because now, the `ptr` array is tied to `a`, which you not always want. In that case you might want

```
ptr[0] = new int(a[0]);
```

This initializes the array with values from `a` but keeps it independent. However,  this introduces manual memory management and this can become tricky in more complex code (memory leaks, double deallocations, dangling pointers), so a more C++ like solution would be (assuming the pointers point to something more interesting than an integer, because now there seems to be no need for pointers).

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> ptrs;

    for(auto i: a)
    {
        ptrs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(i));
    }

    for(auto& i: ptrs)
    {
        std::cout << *i;
    }
}
```